# Wait the end of a function before returning a value

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm working on an app (Ionic) who use the bluetooth.

I have severals pages to connect to my devices. So i created a service to manage the connexion.

This is my service :

```
public async bleConnexion(device) {
this.loader = await this.loadCtrl.create({
  message: "Connexion ..."
})

this.loader.present();      

setTimeout(async () => {
  if (this.isConnected == false) {
    this.displayError();
  }
}, 15000);

this.ble.connect(device.bleID).subscribe(async res => {
  this.loader.dismiss();
  this.isConnected = true;
  console.log(res);
  return true;
}, async error => {
  console.log(error);
  return false;
});

return this.isConnected;
```

}

On my component where i want to connect i need to know if i'm connected or not. But my service return false before end "ble.connect".

How can i do to wait the connexion before returning my value ?

```
var result = this.myService.bleConnexion(myDevice) // return always false (default value of this.isConnected)
```

Comment: Your function will continue to execute the lines of code without waiting for `this.ble.connect` to publish a value. This means `return this.isConnected;` will always be the last value it was set to. The variables `isConnected` and `loader` are shared states, is this what you want? Calling `bleConnexion` multiple times will likely produce incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

Use **async** with **await**.

```
var result = await this.myService.bleConnexion(myDevice);
```

Some explaination :

> The await keyword causes the JavaScript runtime to pause your code on this line, allowing other code to execute in the meantime, until the async function call has returned its result. Once that's complete, your code continues to execute starting on the next line.

From : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: The probleme is i receive the value of this.isConnected before the end of the bleConnect. Si it's always False.